# Can I access a user's friend status using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I am making an web app that shows the authenticated user's friends statuses. Is there anyway I can do this using [Facebook's graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)? The only thing I am finding is `FQL` which I can't use because I am not allowed to use php.

Edit: Also I don't need alot of statuses. I only need their friends latest one.

Edit: fbID is the facebook ID. Here is my code:

```
<script>
var self;
  (function(d){                                                                             // Load the SDK Asynchronously
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {                                             // Init the SDK upon load
    FB.init({
      appId      : '190843834372497', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'http://people.rit.edu/~cds7226/536/project3/channel.html', // Path to your Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {                                              // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
        FB.api('/me', function(me){
          if (me.name) {
            document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
            //Add rest of code here ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            self=me;
          }
        })
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
      } else {                                                                  // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
      }
    });

    document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function(){ // respond to clicks on the login and logout links
      FB.login(function(response){},{scope: 'friends_status,read_stream'});
    });
  } 
</script>
```

Then this function executes when you click the button. It gets the User's last checked in location, and personal information including their facebook ID.

```
function getFriendsCheckin(token)
{
    $.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/recent?oauth_token='+token+'&v='+"20120514",function(results){
    //console.log(results);

    $.each(results['response']['recent'], function(key,value){
        //console.log(key+' : '+value);
        //Friends personal info
        var fullName = value['user']['firstName']+" "+value['user']['lastName'];
        var timeStamp = value['createdAt'];
        var photo = value['user']['photo'];
        var fbID = value['user']['contact']['facebook'];
        //Where they last checked in
        var locName = value['venue']['name'];
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(value['venue']['location']['lat'],value['venue']['location']['lng']);
        //setMarker(location,fullName+'@'+locName);
        setCustomMarker(location,fullName+'@'+locName,fbID,photo);
    });
})
```

}

Lastly this is where the problem is. This function is suppose to show the user's friendd last status when the maker is clicked on google maps.

```
function setCustomMarker(location,title,fbID,icon)
{
//alert("here");
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    draggable: false,
    map: map,
    title: title,
    //icon: icon
    //icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage({url: icon, size: new google.maps.Size({width:10,height:10})})
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
console.log('SELECT status_id,message FROM status WHERE uid='+fbID);
    FB.api(
        {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT status_id,message FROM status WHERE uid='+fbID
        },
        function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    );//*/
});
```

}

Comment: Check out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Comment: How was the lunch ?

Answer (score 1):

May be you are confused, but you can use `fql` with `javascript sdk`.

e.g.

```
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
  },
  function(response) {
    alert('Your name is ' + response[0].name);
  }
);
```

See [reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

If you use graph api, this should work (not tested but you can check and updated me)

```
FB.api('/','POST',{
    access_token:'<your_access_token>',
    batch:[
        {
            "method": "GET",  
            "relative_url": "me/friends?limit=5",
            "name": "get-friends"
        },
        {
            "method": "GET",
            "depends_on":"get-friends",
            "relative_url": "{result=get-friends:$.data.*.id}/statuses"
        }
    ]
},function(response){
     console.log(response);

})
```

*Ofcourse you need permission required for reading status updates of friends.*

Comment: @ChristopherStephenson, I've updated the answer with graph api code to retrieve friend's status. Do check it and report me if its correct :)

Comment: I am keep on getting empty sets from the fql. My query is
    `'SELECT status_id,message FROM status WHERE uid='+fbID` . Also understand what the data var represents in the second example. Lastly, I made sure to ask for friend statuses permissions.

Comment: Post your complete `fql` code . On second question, I dont get what you are trying to ask. Can you rephrase ?

Comment: The code I have is: `FB.api(
   {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT status_id,message FROM status WHERE uid='+fbID
   },
   function(response){
    console.log(response);
   }
  );`
And a link to the site I am working in is: [link](http://people.rit.edu/~cds7226/536/project3/mashup.html). It is a foursquare,facebook, and google maps mashup web app for my class.

Comment: I asked the complete code, how you are asking for permissions. What is `fbID` etc.. And please put your code as an edit to your question. That will help others reading it.

Comment: It is the fbID, I also updated my original post with all the information you requested.

Comment: Your scope is `scope: 'friends_status,read_stream` but you are fetching users status not the friends statuses. First fetch all the ids of friends by `/me/friends` and then pass those `ids` in place of `fbID` . My second example does the same thing, why dont you try it ?

Comment: But, I am already getting the friends facebook user ID from foursquare.

Comment: Can you try with some other friend ? May be that particular friend has restriced showing his status. Also, `console.log(fbID);` and verify if you are getting a valid `fbID`. Also, go to [graph api explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and do this `graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT status_id,message FROM status WHERE uid=<fbID>`. Check if it works for you with that `fbID`. Graph api explorer returns empty data only when I enter an invalid `fbID`

Comment: I got: {
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}

Comment: Where do you get this error ? Also, SO is suggesting me to continue in chat but you dont have enought repo for that. Read my comments again. Try on your own. If that doesnt help you, we can chat at jashwantsingh@gmail[dot]com

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FB.api('user_id/statuses','GET',{
    //friends_status access token
});
```

Comment: that wont work... message = "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: user_id";

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be done with the help of [graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

In the reference doc - take a look at the profile feed API call. There in that sample replace me with the user-id of the friend whose feed you are trying to access.

However, to do so via an app, you need to ask for read_stream and friends_status permissions from the user who is trying to use your app.

From my experience using client side Facebook js-sdk to handle OAuth is the easiest thing to do.

For the apps hosted on heroku, they provide sample implementation of client side OAuth handling and that is very useful. (To be able to host your app on heroku - while creating your app in developers.facebook.com/apps just make sure to choose "Host the project on Heroku" option.